# SQL Server 2014: Products sold count by each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, pivot

I have an Employee table and a Product table. A 3rd table (ProductsSold) contains an EmployeeID, ProductID, DateSold.

The ProductsSold table contains a product sold by an employee on a specific date.

I am trying to get the count of each product sold by each employee (even if the employee sold 0 products they need to show up)

[image: sample]

```
select e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName, count(*) as c
from ProductsSold ps 
    inner join product p on ps.productid = p.productid
    inner join employee e on ps.employeeid = e.employeeid
group by e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName
order by e.EmployeeName
```

Do I need to write a Pivot query? This is going to become an SSRS report. Does SSRS support Pivot queries?

Comment: So the products table contains only 2 products?

Comment: For now yes. But it could increase too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the results of the query in SSRS, it's better to just send the data unpivoted. You can add a matrix in your report to do the pivoting work for you.

Your query had two issues,

1. It was just counting how many sales records it found
2. As your primary table is the sales and you are doing an inner join to employees, only employees with sales records would appear.

Below is some sample data I used and a query at the end to get the results you want.

```
DECLARE @employees TABLE(EmployeeID int, EmployeeName varchar(64))
DECLARE @products TABLE(ProductID int, ProductName varchar(64))
DECLARE @sales TABLE(EmployeeID int, ProductID int, Qty int, SaleDate date)

INSERT INTO @employees VALUES (1, 'Dave'), (2,'Bob'), (3, 'Mary')
INSERT INTO @products VALUES (1, 'Cars'), (2, 'Bikes'), (3, 'Trucks') 
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES 
    (1,1,5, '2019-04-30'), (1,1,10, '2019-04-30'), (1,2,11, '2019-04-29'), 
    (2,1,12, '2019-04-28'), (2,2,13, '2019-04-30'), (2,3,14, '2019-04-29')


SELECT 
        e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
    FROM @employees e 
    LEFT JOIN @sales s on e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN @products p on s.ProductID = p.ProductID
group by e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName
order by e.EmployeeName
```

This time we start with the employees and `LEFT JOIN` to the other tables. This ensures all employees will appear.

Based on the sample data above the results are

[image]

If yuo use this as a dataset query in SSRS you can then add a matrix with a Row Group for Employee and a Column Group for Product, the 'cell' values will be `=SUM(Fields!Qty.Value)`

This will give you a report that looks like this.. (forgive the formatting, this was literally 2 minutes work)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tablix control in SSRS to do this using the query you designed.  Though you should change your join to the Employee table in the query to an outer join to make sure they still show in cases where they had no sales.  You would use both row and column grouping in the tablix.  The column group will basically do a pivot for you by creating columns for each unique value you are grouping on.  A row group would create a row for each unique value it groups on.  Check out the following link to get more information on using groups in SSRS

[Understanding Groups (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: this is the reduced fat version of my answer ! :)